# How to create a matrix of sampled values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to create a matrix (*M*-by-*N*), taking `M` contiguous samples and putting them in a column of the matrix. So, the sequence is *x[0],x[1],...,x[MN-1]* where *N = 0,1,2,...,n* and the matrix looks like mathematically

```
A = [x_0, x_M,.....,x_{M(N-1)};
     x_1, x_M+1,....,x_{M(N-1)+1}; 
     . ......;
     :   :   :;
     x_{M-1},x_{2M-1},....,x_{MN-1}]
```

Please help

Comment: Shouldn't your loop run all the way to `M*N`? Also, once you have `x`, to get `A` just use `reshape(x,M,N)`. Lastly, your loop you rather contain `x(i) = 4*x(i-1)*(1-x(i-1))`

Comment: @Dan: reshape is not even needed.

Comment: @Dan: You are absolutely right in pointing out about the looping of the equation-it should have been x(i-1) in the right hand side. Secondly, he loop should run from 0 to MN-1 or from 1 to MN. The question is based on the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0362.pdf  Eq(7) is the matrix phi which I have called as matrix A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab allows linear indexing, i.e. in a 4-by-4 array `M`, `M(15)==M(3,4)`. Consequently, you can fill your array without even needing to reshape:

```
M = 50;
N = 100;
A = zeros(M,N);
A(1) = 0.1;
for i = 2:N*M %// loop until the very last element
    A(i) = 4*A(i-1)*(1-A(i-1));
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't this then be `x=zeros(M,N)` in the beginning? Also, you still need to add the `-1` in the indexing of the RHS `x` calls

Comment: @Dan: Yes, indeed. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas: Thank you for your reply. Something is unclear, could you please check -- (1) Shouldn't A(1) be x(1) and the equation/function be iterated using using x(1) instead of A(1)?  (2) The question is based on the paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0362.pdf  Eq(7) in the paper is the matrix phi which I have called as matrix A. Also, based on answers given by others should there be a reshape() ?

Comment: @Sm1: I apologize for the mistake with renaming. I meant to replace all `x` with `A`, and messed up one. There is no reshape needed, since you can index into a 2D array with a linear index that runs down the first column, then the second, etc, and thus addresses the elements in exactly the right order as you want.

Answer (score 1):

I give you another solution.

If I understand you correctly, you have `x` vector, so need to create matrix `A`. All tight things here - positioning of elements.
We can do it this way (I will use a smaller values of `M,N` just for example):

```
M = 10;
N = 5;
x(1) = 0.1;
for ii = 2:M*N
    x(ii) = 4*x(ii-1)*(1 - x(ii-1));
end
A = vec2mat(x,M)'; %'
```

P.S. Another interesting issue - how to create `x` using a vectorization approach... But I am still thinking about it...

---

For the sake of curiosity, I compared my approach to [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724/dan)'s approach:

```
tic; A = vec2mat(x,M)';toc %'
Elapsed time is 0.037790 seconds.
tic; A = reshape(x,M,N); toc
Elapsed time is 0.000016 seconds.
```

Yeeeep, there is no sense to use `vec2mat` - `reshape` is awesome!

Comment: Thank you for your effort. If my understanding is right, I should be using reshape() after the for loop ends?

Comment: Exactly! Main difference between my answer and @Jonas answer - if you need to use `x` later in your program - use mine, if you don't need it - use Jonas, it will be faster

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam: note that if you need `x` later in the program, you can just use `A(:)` instead.

Comment: @Jonas ah, of course, stupid mistake! So, the best way is to avoid using `vec2mat`, `reshape` and `x`! By the way - are there approach to create `A` (or `x`) using vectorization?